# how display in Thymeleaf List<Entity>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

hello I would like to display a list of message and date but don't know how, I already find some code (Model and Themeleaf) but I can't change it properly :> my code: 
Service

```
@Autowired
private SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

private List<Spittle> spittles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Spittle("aaaa", new Date()),
        new Spittle("bbbbbb", new Date())
));

public List<Spittle> findSpittles() {
     List<Spittle> spittles = new ArrayList<>();
     spittleRepository.findAll().forEach(findedSpittles::add);
     return findedSpittles;
}}
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
SpittleService spittleService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findSpittles(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("spittle", spittleService.findSpittles());
    return "spittles";
} }
```

Entity

```
        @Id
        private final Long id;
        private final String message;
        private final Date time;
        private Double latitude;
        private Double longitude;



        public Spittle(String message, Date time, Double latitude, Double 
        longitude) {
            this.id = null;
            this.message = message;
            this.time = time;
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public Spittle(String message, Date time) {
            this(message, time, null, null);
        }

        + geters
}}
```

Thymeleaf

```
<h2>Lista spiltów</h2>
       <table class="table table-striped">
           <tr>
               <th>Message</th>
               <th>Date</th>
           </tr>
           <tr th:each="spittle : ${spittle}">
               <td th:text="${spittle.getMessage()}"></td>
               <td th:text="${spittle.getTime()}"></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
```

Repository don't have any code inside just extend JpaRepository

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
         <tr th:each="spittle : ${spittles}">
               <td th:text="${spittle.message}"></td>
               <td th:text="${spittle.time}"></td>
           </tr>
```

You might need to use `date.format` for formatting your date.

Comment: now I get error "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "spittle.spittles" (template: "spittles" - line 16, col 40)" I delete "time" but still getting error. Maybe I should change something in my classes ?

Comment: when you debug are you getting list of Spittle on your controller. I have a feeling your list is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Try this changes,

**Controller**

```
@Autowired
SpittleService spittleService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Spittle> findSpittles(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("spittles", spittleService.findSpittles());
    return "spittles";
} }
```

**Service**

```
public List<Spittle> findSpittles() {
     List<Spittle> spittles = new ArrayList<>();
     spittles = spittleRepository.findAll().forEach(findedSpittles::add);
     return spittles;
}}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr th:each="spittle : ${spittles}">
  <td th:text="${spittle.message}"></td>
  <td th:text="${spittle.time}"></td>
</tr>
```